# Prior distribution on Bayesian T Test?

Tags: bayesian, t-test, prior

I have two subgroups of structure (bone structure) and I want to test if there is any difference of size (area) between them, and if there is, how important this difference is. The first set is a group non-heated, and the second was heated. I wanted to do a Bayesian T-test (Mann-Whitney because my data isn't normal and the variance of the two groups isn't equal).

I am just not sure about the prior distribution to set for the test. I understand what is a prior distribution but I am not sure if I have any ... My take is that if I had some information about my priors, I think it would be more clear than that and I would know. Is it better to keep the default prior in JASP (cauchy = 0,707) if I am not sure about the priors distribution (I've seen this in some publications)? Is it often that we can't add some priors knowledge to those tests?

Comment: ". I wanted to do a Bayesian T-test (Mann-Whitney because my data isn't normal and the variance of the two groups isn't equal)." - what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed a couple of ideas.   A $t$-test is a parametric test (although the Bayesian $t$-test can relax the assumptions) while the Wilcoxon test treats Y as ordinal and uses only its rank ordering.  To get a Wilcoxon test, use its generalization the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model.  The `blrm` function in the R `rmsb` package makes this easy and detailed case studies may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/R/rmsb).

For the Bayesian $t$-test read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BEST/vignettes/BEST.pdf) and see examples in [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr). BBR also has more background information about using the proportional odds model to get a Wilcoxon test.

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell. I read the section about assumption being more flexible with bayesian model in the link BBR. I thought they were as important as in the ''classic'' t-test, and particularly after reading some publication. I have a LOT of tests to do,~600 groups to compare (300 non-heated and 300 of the heated counterpart) and for 10 variables. Not all the samples are normal, not all the variance are equal, but the majority are. I wanted to apply the same test to all for comparison purpose. I am not sure how a bayesian model can relaxe those assumptions and if it can apply to my data?

Comment: Like this publication (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330569075_The_JASP_Guidelines_for_Conducting_and_Reporting_a_Bayesian_Analysis)

Comment: The most important Bayesian contribution besides making a $t$-test much more robust is in handling the 600 groups and 10 variables by having a unified model, perhaps a hierarchical one that borrows information.  Any time you rely on significance tests, and especially any time do you many of them, expect bad things to happen.